# Masonry destroy and initialize again

Tags: media-queries, jquery-masonry, destroy, recreate

I have initialize masonry plugin - works OK,

than I destroy it for media width <= 767px - it was destroyed

but when I return back to media width > 767px and initialize masonry again it doesn't work.

why?

or is there any another solution to turn off masonry plugin and later turn it on on some event?

this is my code:

```
var masonryData = {
    isInitLayout: true,
    isResizeBound: false,
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 300,
    gutter: 20,
    transitionDuration: '0.5s'
};

function initializeMasonry(masonryData){
    if (jQuery().masonry) {
        var masonryContainer = jQuery('.masonry').masonry(masonryData);
        jQuery(masonryContainer).imagesLoaded(function(){
            jQuery(masonryContainer).masonry(masonryData);
        });
    }
}

function destroyMasonry(){
    if (jQuery().masonry) {
        jQuery('.masonry').masonry();
        jQuery('.masonry').masonry('destroy');
    }
}
```

I'm using enquire plugin so I use match/unmatch methods for js media queries:

```
$.Site.Match.smallScreen = function() {
   ...
   destroyMasonry();
   ...
}

$.Site.Match.mediumScreen = function() {
   ...
   initializeMasonry(masonryData);
   ...
}
```

Many thanks for help

Comment: I try to use reloadItems method and set container position to relative. It works OK.

Answer (score 7):

Finally after hours of reading the docs, I found that masonry will make a $.data('masonry') to masonry element.

You can read more about it in masonry docs [here](https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#jquery-fn-data-masonry).

This data will affect the items position in masonry. So, we need to remove this data with $.removeData('masonry') after we destroy the masonry.

```
// init masonry
$('.masonry-container').masonry();

// destroy masonry
$('.masonry-container').masonry('destroy');
$('.masonry-container').removeData('masonry'); // This line to remove masonry's data

// re-init masonry again. The position will be nice
$('.masonry-container').masonry();
```

Comment: Almost quite on this....$.removeData('masonry') did the trick

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I ended up solving this a different way. Masonry is just setting some styles. So using a media query, I set the following CSS to basically render masonry useless:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .item {
    position: relative !important;
    left: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Now, I always initialize masonry, and never uninitialize/reinitialize it. It's on all the time, but CSS media queries with `!important` take priority over the inline styles set by Masonry.

Answer (score 1):

[Eli Gassert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085828/2290316) might be more clever than going all javascript.

However, I found myself doing this quite successfully like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function (event) {
  var $window = $(window);

  if ($window.width() < 768) {
    var $masonryTarget = $('.masonry-container'),
        $hasMasonry = $masonryTarget.data('masonry') ? true : false
    ;
    if ($masonryTarget.length > 0 && $hasMasonry) {
      // Destroy masonry if exists.
      $masonryTarget.masonry('destroy');
    }
  } else {
    // Enable all masonry instances.
    $('.mansonry-container').masonry({
      'itemSelector': '.masonry-item',
      'columnWidth': '.masonry-item'
    });
  }
});
```

The basic idea is that masonry, initialized as a jQuery plugin is stored in a data attribute. If a masonry data attribute is defined, we destroy the instance.

Might be worth mentioning [that debouncing this function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) improves a lot the performance.

Comment: I found `if($(".my-element').data('masonry')) { /* do something */ }` useful on a page where sometimes my destroy method ended up called before the masonry object had been initialised, resulting in a console error like _masonry.pkgd.min.js:9 masonry not initialized. Cannot call methods, i.e. $().masonry("destroy")_

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($(window).width() <= 767) {

    $('#container').masonry( 'destroy' );

} 

if ($(window).width() > 768) {

    $('#container').masonry({
      columnWidth: 350,
      gutter: 20,
    });

} 

if ($(window).width() > 992) {

    $('#container').masonry({
      columnWidth: 300,
      gutter: 20,
    });

} 


if ($(window).width() > 1200) {

    $('#container').masonry({
      columnWidth: 270,
      gutter: 20,
    });

}
```

});

Comment: This doesn't solve the question. It only works on initial page load, whereas the question is asking about `onresize`.

Comment: So just put the statements in a function and call it onresize.